# Java -- For an animation, how should a logic class notify a loosely coupled view to repaint

Tags: java, animation, observer-pattern, repaint

For an application that repaints frequently, how should the 'model' notify the 'views' that they need to repeatedly repaint one of their components. This:

```
class AppLogic extends Observable {
  void runAnimation() {
    while (isAnimationRunning) {
      modifyDataStructures();
      setChanged();
      notifyObservers();
      Thread.sleep(25);
    }
  }
}
```

class View extends JComponent implements Observer {
  void update(Observable o) {
    o.getData();
    innerPanel.repaint();
  }
}

seems like a terrible way to go about animating a panel, especially if the animation is being repainted most of the time that the program is running. Any suggestions? Thanks.

*Ignore the obvious errors in threading and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are building a kind of "Dashboard" application that updates the information periodically, do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264220/java-for-an-animation-how-should-a-logic-class-notify-a-loosely-coupled-view/5264915#5264915) says. If you want something more advanced (like animations for a game) you need more work. Check [this article](http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/15969-double-buffering-movement-collision-detection.html) for some interesting tidbits about game programming and animation in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "running" the business logic, you could use a Swing Timer in the View component and just ask the business model to paint itself, e.g passing the current time as a parameter.